# How to find people with direct reports, without showing the direct reports in Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to find all users in active directory that have people reporting to them, but I cant find any code examples that allows me to exclude people in my search that do not have any direct reports.

Can anybody help me with this? LDAP completely confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how I have done solved a similar problem to what you have described. I hope this helps.

```
DirectorySearcher searcher;
SearchResultCollection results;

searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DirectReports");
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
searcher.SearchRoot = utilityDomain;

Dictionary<string, string> managerEmailAddresses = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using (searcher)
{
    results = searcher.FindAll();

    foreach (SearchResult result in results)
    {
        if (result.Properties["DirectReports"].Count > 0)
        {
            DirectoryEntry emp = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

            String mail = "";
            if (emp.Properties["mail"].Count > 0)
            {
                mail = emp.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
                string userName;
                userName= mail.Split('@')[0];

                managerEmailAddresses.Add(userName, mail);
             }
         }
    }
    return managerEmailAddresses;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a filter like this? `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(directReports=*))`?